# 2 directive in one bootstrap form-group not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, directive

i have a bootstrap form-group in which I have 2 directive

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Name" class="col-md-2">Name</label>
                        <sw-textbox id="Name" sw-class="col-md-3" sw-model="Entity.Name" />


                        <label for="Family" class="col-md-2">Family</label>
                        <sw-textbox id ="Family" sw-class="col-md-3" sw-model="Entity.Family" />

                    </div>
```

and my directive is like

```
app.directive('swTextbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E,A',
        scope:
            {
                swModel: '=',
                swWidth: '=',
                swHeight: '=',
                swNullable: '=',
                swReadonly: '=',
                swDisable: '=',
                swVisible: '=',
                swMultiline: '=',
                swClass: '@',
                swChangedValue: '&changedvalue'
            },
        template: '<input type="text" dir="rtl" ng-model="swModel" ng-model-options="{updateOn: \'blur\'}" ng-change="swChangedValue({newVal: swModel})" />',
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            if (scope.swMultiline) {
                var htm = '<textarea dir="rtl"  ng-model="swModel" ng-model-options="{updateOn: \'blur\'}" ng-change="swChangedValue({newVal: swModel})"';
                if (angular.isDefined(attr.id))
                    htm += 'id="' + attr['id'] + '"';
                if (scope.swDisable)
                    htm += ' disabled';
                if (scope.swReadonly)
                    htm += ' readonly';
                if (scope.swHeight != undefined || scope.swWidth != undefined || scope.swNullable != undefined) {
                    htm += ' style="';
                    if (scope.swHeight != undefined)
                        htm += 'max-height:' + scope.swHeight + 'px; height:' + scope.swHeight + 'px;';
                    if (scope.swWidth != undefined)
                        htm += 'max-width:' + scope.swWidth + 'px; width:' + scope.swWidth + 'px;';
                    if (scope.swReadonly == undefined && scope.swDisable == undefined && scope.swNullable != undefined)
                        htm += 'background-color:#fcf3f8;';
                    htm += '"';
                }
                htm += '></textarea>';
                el.find('input').replaceWith(htm);
            }
            else {
                scope.$watch('swWidth', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                    el.find('input').css('width', newValue);
                });
                scope.$watch('swNullable', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                    el.find('input').css('background-color', (!newValue) ? '#fcf3f8' : '');
                });
                scope.$watch('swReadonly', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                    el.find('input').attr('disabled', newValue);
                    el.find('input').css('background-color', (newValue) ? '#f3f3f3' : (scope.swNullable == undefined || scope.swNullable) ? '' : '#fcf3f8');
                });
                scope.$watch('swDisable', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                    el.find('input').attr('disabled', newValue);
                    el.find('input').css('background-color', (newValue) ? '#f3f3f3' : (scope.swNullable == undefined || scope.swNullable) ? '' : '#fcf3f8');
                });
                scope.$watch('swVisible', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                    if (newValue != undefined)
                        el.find('input').css('display', (newValue) ? '' : 'none');
                });
                scope.$watch('swClass', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                    if (newValue != undefined)
                        el.find('input').addClass(newValue);
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

when i use the sw-textbox separatelyin form there is not any problem but whenever i use it like this 
the second sw-textbox is not rendering

what could be the reason ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a trailing solidus is the likely problem. Try using end tags.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="col-md-2">Name</label>
    <sw-textbox id="Name" sw-class="col-md-3" sw-model="Entity.Name"></sw-textbox>
    <label for="Family" class="col-md-2">Family</label>
    <sw-textbox id ="Family" sw-class="col-md-3" sw-model="Entity.Family"></sw-textbox>
</div>
```

Check out this quick plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ZX4sgkoaKbBZxOGKsLTQ